# Accessing current row values in a trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, jsonb

I created a function will insert a value into a json for each row inserted in a table.

But when I execute the insert, it says me that the column doesn't exist.

Here is the function  :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_id_function()
RETURNS trigger AS'
BEGIN
  NEW.previewcontent = previewcontent || ''{"id":1}'';
RETURN NEW;
END;'
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Here is the trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_id_trigger
BEFORE INSERT
ON "Telnet"
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_id_function();
```

Here is the error :

```
`ERROR:  column "previewcontent" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT previewcontent || '{"id":1}'`
```

Here is my table definition :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a column of the `NEW` record:

```
NEW.previewcontent = NEW.previewcontent || ''{"id":1}'';
```

If the type of `previewcontent` is jsonb use `jsonb_build_object()` to add the current value of `id` to the jsonb column:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_id_function()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.previewcontent = NEW.previewcontent || jsonb_build_object('id', NEW.id);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Comment: ahah what a mistake ! Thank you ! Do you know How I can get the ID that will be used for this insert statement? Thanks

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much !